# Is it ok to initialize exports asynchronously in a node.js module?

Tags: model-view-controller, design-patterns, mongodb, asynchronous, node.js

As MongoDB database access and initialization is asynchronous on Node.js, I would like to define one module per collection that exports wrapped db calls after db initialization.

Such a "Cars.model.js" module looks like that:

```
var db = require("mongodb");
db.collection("cars", function(err, col) {
    exports.getCars = function(callback) {
        col.find({}, callback);
    };
});
```

so that other modules can run:

```
var carModel = require("Cars.model.js").getCars;
getCars(err, cars) {
    // (do something with cars here...)
};
```

It happened to me that `getCars` was undefined, because db access was not yet initialized at the time my second module was run.

How do you deal with creating such asynchronous db models?

Comment: I've tested this with Node 6.9 and 7.2 and it works

Answer (score 11):

You cannot write to `exports` after you've left the file. You must be blocking. To avoid being blocking I would use lazy loading of resources.

```
var carCol;
var carEmitter = new require("events").EventEmitter;


exports.getCars = function(callback) {
  // if no car collection then bind to event
  if (carCol === undefined) {
    carEmitter.on("cars-ready", function() {
      callback(carCol);
    });
  } else {
    // we have cars, send them back
    callback(carCol);
  }
}

db.collection("cars", function(err, col) {
  // store cars
  carCol = col;
  // tell waiters that we have cars.
  carEmitter.emit("cars-ready");
});
```

Use event emitters to emulate lazy loading. You may want to generalize to a `LazyLoadedCollection` class/object to make the code neater / more DRY.

Comment: @adrienjoly not very DRY or extendable though!

Comment: I believe that most of the asynchronous complexity could be moved to the application init module, by populating a collection cache before any logic (and thus, models) is run. I will propose some code as soon as stackoverflow allows me to answer my own question (in 5 hours now) ;-)

Comment: @adrienjoly I would recommend againts blocking in your init until it's loaded. Best to let it load in the background and add requests for the data to a buffer whilst it's loading.

Comment: i did that first, but my application modules could not compile until the collection callbacks were triggered by the asynchronous db loader, because of the models' exports defined in the callback...

Comment: You CAN write to module.exports asynchronously actually

Answer (score 2):

I'm a newbe so don't be mad at me...

I'm using promises to do so:

```
var db = require("mongodb"),
Q = require('q'),
getCarsDefer = Q.defer();

exports.getCars = getCarsDefer.promise;

db.collection("cars", function(err, col) {
  if(err){
    getCarsDefer.reject(err);
  }else{
     getCarsDefer.resolve(Q.ninvoke(col,'find'));
  };
});
```

So you can get your cars like that:

```
var carModel = require("Cars.model.js").getCars;
getCars.then(cars) {
    // (do something with cars here...)
};
```

It this is a bad idea, please let me know because it's what i'm doing right now.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this simple solution works: replace the asynchronous call to `getCars()` by a synchronous call to a collection cache that would be populated *before* models can be called.

The main.js application starter module:

```
var db = require("mongodb");
exports.collectionCache = {};
db.collection("cars", function(err, col) {
    exports.collectionCache["cars"] = col;
    // ready => start application logic (incl. models) here
});
```

Thus "Cars.model.js" would look like that:

```
var col = require("main").collectionCache; // populated
exports.getCars = function(callback) {
    col["cars"].find({}, callback);
};
```

This solution moves the asynchronous problem from models to the root database model, making models simpler to develop.

Comment: This also increases server start up time because you have to wait for all the collections to be loaded. I also have my doubts this works because your writing to `exports` asynchronously and I don't know whether exports is copied by reference or by value.

Comment: Indeed, it does increase server startup time, but simplifies the development of models, and optimizes the number of simultaneous opened collections.

Comment: Concerning the asynchronous population of `exports.collectionCache`, I believe that it is correct, as javascript objects are always kept as references. It would not work if I was redefining this export asynchronously, though.

Comment: I still think your logic is backwards. Models.js should not require `main`. You just need to think asynchronous not synchronous. Your solving the problem with a hack.

Comment: the most important things for me are that the code works, is readable and easy to maintain. i don't mind hacking! ^^