# Design pattern for shared database handle in Node.JS

Tags: database, node.js, design-patterns

How do I share a database connection across various NodeJS modules? The example I have found all had a monolithic structure where the entire code was in one single app.js file.

```
/* main.js */
var foo = require("./foo"); 
/* express stuff ...*/
mysql = /* establish mysql connection */ 
app.get("/foo", foo.hello ); 


/* foo.js */
exports.hello = function(req, res) {
   res.send("Hello from the foo module!"); 
}
```

How would I access "mysql" from my module "foo"? What is the recommended design pattern for this?

Comment: It seems that [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10328308/574501) is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the module pattern to easily pass your db object (and anything else) to modules that need it.

```
// users.js
module.exports = function( options ) {
    var db = options.db;
    var pants = options.pants;  // or whatever

    return {
        GetUser: function( userID, callback ) {
            db.query("....", function (err, results) {
                callback(results)
            });
        },
        AnotherFunc: function (...) {},
        AndAnotherFunc: function (...) {}
    };
};
```

You use this module like:

```
// make your db connection here

var users = require('./users.js')({
    db: db,
    pants: 'blue'
});

users.GetUser( 32, function( user ) {
    console.log("I got the user!");
    console.log( user );
});
```

I find this to be a great way to write modules, as it's a lot like making an actual Class object, like in C++.  You can even simulate 'private' methods/parameters.

Answer (score 0):

I usually put mysql handle in a different file (module) and require the module in different routes.

I believe you also have to connect to mysql asynchronously, you can refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6425290/is-it-ok-to-initialize-exports-asynchronously-in-a-node-js-module), which uses a callback function to solve the problem.

Comment: As far I know MongoClient.connect() automatically creates a connection pool. How do you approach this https://github.com/mscdex/node-mariasql - if you have any experience here?